# How to enable (or set up) MySQL to use "group commit"?

Tags: mysql, optimization, commit

I've read a lot of good reviews of MySQL Group Commit, which was broken in MySQL 4.x but was fixed in 5.1 and 5.5. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-performance-group_commit.html

But I could not find any document showing how to enable (or set up) Group Commit in MySQL 5.5. The above link only says sync_binlog needs to be set to 0 for group commit to support binary log. But it does not mention any config variable to turn on group commit.

Maybe Group Commit is an internal optimization in MySQL that's always "enabled" without a user doing any explicit config change?

Comment: From that same page: `Group commit is transparent; you do not need to do anything to take advantage of this significant performance improvement.`